# activepage not updating within nested component in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use this onChange function from a third party library for table pagination, it provides the pagenum when you click on a page number, and I can then provide that to my table, from a separate library. But when I call the changePage function to update the table with new pagenumber it doesn't update. I tried to bind the function once and it did update, then it threw an error 'bind of undefined' etc. How do I get it to update?

```
class DataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opent: false,
      openid: null,
      activePage: 1,
    };
    this.ttipOpenHandler = this.ttipOpenHandler.bind(this);
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
    this.options = {
      alwaysShowAllBtns: props.alwaysShowAllBtns,
      defaultSortName: props.defaultSortName,
      defaultSortOrder: props.defaultSortOrder,
      firstPage: props.firstPage,
      hideSizePerPage: props.hideSizePerPage,
      lastPage: props.lastPage,
      nextPage: props.nextPage,
      noDataText: props.noDataText,
      paginationShowsTotal: props.paginationShowsTotal,
      paginationSize: props.paginationSize,
      paginationPanel: (pgprops) => {
        console.log();
        return (
          <div>
            <Pagination
              activePage={this.state.activePage}
              itemsCountPerPage={20}
              totalItemsCount={props.data.length}
              pageRangeDisplayed={5}
              onChange={(pagenum) => {
                pgprops.changePage(pagenum);// THIS
                this.setState({ activePage: pagenum });
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
      },
      prePage: props.prePage,
      sizePerPage: props.sizePerPage,
      withFirstAndLast: props.withFirstAndLast,
    };
  }

  // only show tooltip for truncated text.
  ttipOpenHandler = (event) => {
    let openttip = null;
    const e = event.target;
    const diff = e.scrollHeight - e.offsetHeight;
    if (diff > 1) {
      openttip = true;
    } else {
      openttip = false;
    }

    const eid = event.target.dataset.openid;
    this.setState({ opent: openttip, openid: eid });
  }

  handlePageChange = (pagenum, changepage) => {
    changepage(this.state.activePage);
    this.setState({ activePage: pagenum });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.activePage);
    return (
      <div className={CLASS_NAME}>
        <BootstrapTable
          bodyContainerClass={this.props.bodyContainerClass}
          bordered={this.props.bordered}
          condensed={this.props.condensed}
          containerClass={this.props.containerClass}
          containerStyle={this.props.containerStyle}
          data={this.props.data}
          expandComponent={this.props.expandComponent}
          expandableRow={this.props.expandableRow}

          headerContainerClass={this.props.headerContainerClass}
          height={this.props.height}
          hover={this.props.hover}
          keyField={this.props.keyField}
          options={this.options}
          pagination={this.props.pagination}
          tableBodyClass={this.props.tableBodyClass}
          tableContainerClass={this.props.tableContainerClass}
          tableHeaderClass={`datatable-custom-header ${this.props.tableHeaderClass}`}
          tableStyle={this.props.tableStyle}
          trClassName={this.props.trClassName}
          width={this.props.width}
        >
          {_.map(this.props.columns, o => (
            <TableHeaderColumn
              caretRender={o.caretRender}
              className={o.colHeaderCss}
              columnClassName={`${o.colCss} custom-td`}
              headerAlign={o.headerAlign}
              dataAlign={o.dataAlign}
              dataField={o.key}
              dataFormat={(cell, row, smth, index) => (<div className="cell-container">{o.formatter ? o.formatter(cell, row, smth, index, ReadTooltip, this.ttipOpenHandler) : <ReadTooltip data-openid={`${this.props.columns.indexOf(o)}${index}`} title={cell} open={this.state.opent && `${this.props.columns.indexOf(o)}${index}` === `${this.state.openid}`} onOpen={this.ttipOpenHandler} placement={this.props.ttipplacement}><div className="line-clamp-2">{cell}</div></ReadTooltip>}</div>)}
              dataSort={o.dataSort}
              isKey={o.isPrimaryKey}
              key={o.key}
              sortFunc={o.sortFunc}
              width={o.width}
            >
              {o.text}
            </TableHeaderColumn>
          ))}
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using the binded `handlePageChange` handler in `onChange` event?

Comment: bc that wasn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

`this` can only be accessed in binded functions part of the `DataTable` component used by the `Pagination` component. Thus, to set the active page in `DataTable`, the handler should be binded.

`pgprops` is passed from the `BootstrapTable` component.

Merging these will have:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
}

setActivePage(pagenum) {
  this.setState({
    activePage: pagenum,
  });
}

handlePageChange = (pgprops, pagenum) => {
  pgprops.changePage(pagenum);
  this.setActivePage(pagenum);
}

// options
paginationPanel: (pgprops) => {
  onChange = (pagenum) => (pgprops, pagenum) => this.handlePageChange(pgprops, pagenum),
}
```